# Wait before a javascript function can be called again

Tags: javascript, function

I've looked at many different solutions to this, none of which worked. I know it has something to do with setTimeout, but I don't know how to implement it properly.

```
function myfunction()
{
//the function
//wait for 1 second before it can be ran again
}
```

To clarify: I don't want to call the function at a regular interval, I want to be able to enforce a delay before the function can be called again.

Comment: `setTimeout(myfunction, 1000)`

Comment: Do you want to wait one second and then automatically call the function again, or do you want to enforce a delay of one second before it's possible to run the function?

Comment: I want to enforce a delay before it can be ran again, after having been called.

Comment: @user3788705 Will it be called repeatedly in succession or do you want something like: `1 second`: call it, then, at `t = 2 seconds`, you are allowed to call it again; however, you don't have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest solution would be to hold a `boolean` variable and reset it to `true` after a given `delay`.

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/3zkuG/)

**HTML**

```
<button id="clickme">click me!</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var canGo = true,
    delay = 1000; // one second
var myFunction = function () {
    if (canGo) {
        canGo = false;
        // do whatever you want
        alert("Hi!");
        setTimeout(function () {
            canGo = true;
        }, delay)
    } else {
        alert("Can't go!");
    }
}


$("#clickme").click(function(){
    myFunction();
})
```

With this, you hold a boolean, `canGo`, and set it to `true`. If the function is run, it sets `canGo` to false and sets a `setTimeout()` for a time period of `delay`, in milliseconds. If you try to run the function again, it won't run and will, instead, `alert("Can't go!")`. This was just for demonstrative purposes; you don't need that part. After `delay`, `canGo` will be set to `true`, and you will be able to once more run the function.

Comment: "Easiest"? I think there are ways that require less code and aren't dependent on setTimeout, so "easier" for me. ;-)

Comment: @RobG I should've said "I think the easiest way…". Semantics. Also, a lot of that code is there for demonstrative purposes. It could easily be stripped down to the length of the other answers.

Comment: @Luxelin—just pointing out that it has an unnecessary reliance on *setTimeout* and global variables and isn't particularly concise.

Answer (score 4):

```
var lastTime = 0;

function myFunction() {
    var now = new Date().getTime(); // Time in milliseconds
    if (now - lasttime < 1000) {
        return;
    } else {
        lastTime = now;
    }
    // rest of function
}
```

Comment: I was going to do that, but keep the *lastTime* variable in a closure.

Comment: I think this should be the right answer because using a timestamp is better than running a timer!

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use setTimeout at all. The following is similar to other answers, but uses a closure to remember the last time the function ran rather than a global variable.

```
var myFunction = function() {
  var lastTime = new Date();
  return function() {
    var now = new Date();
    if ((now - lastTime) < 1000) return;
    lastTime = now; 

    /* do stuff */

  };
}());
```

Comment: +1 for using a closure to avoid cluttering the global namespace

Answer (score 1):

```
var lastRan = 0;

var myFunction = function() {
  var now = Date.now();
  if(now-lastRan < 1000) {
      return;
  }

  lastRan = now;

  //rest of function
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to run your function again after a set time, you can use setTimeout and pass it the function to run and the delay period in milliseconds.

```
function myfunction() {
    //the function

    //run again in one second
    setTimeout(myfunction, 1000);
}
```

Edited based on poster's comments:

```
var waiting = false;

var myfunction = function() {
    if (!waiting) {
        //Run some code

        waiting = setTimeout(function() {
            waiting = false;
        }, 1000);
    }
};
```

Comment: It's unfortunate the the OP didn't make his question clearer. See his remarks in the comments - this is not an answer.

Comment: I don't want it to run every second, I want there to be a delay before it's allowed to run again.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use throttle or debounce from underscore.js

http://underscorejs.org/#throttle

> throttle_.throttle(function, wait, [options])
>
> Creates and returns a
>   new, throttled version of the passed function, that, when invoked
>   repeatedly, will only actually call the original function at most once
>   per every wait milliseconds. Useful for rate-limiting events that
>   occur faster than you can keep up with.
>
> By default, throttle will execute the function as soon as you call it
>   for the first time, and, if you call it again any number of times
>   during the wait period, as soon as that period is over. If you'd like
>   to disable the leading-edge call, pass {leading: false}, and if you'd
>   like to disable the execution on the trailing-edge, pass  {trailing:
>   false}.

```
var throttled = _.throttle(updatePosition, 100);
$(window).scroll(throttled);
```

http://underscorejs.org/#debounce

> debounce_.debounce(function, wait, [immediate])
>
> Creates and returns a
>   new debounced version of the passed function which will postpone its
>   execution until after wait milliseconds have elapsed since the last
>   time it was invoked. Useful for implementing behavior that should only
>   happen after the input has stopped arriving. For example: rendering a
>   preview of a Markdown comment, recalculating a layout after the window
>   has stopped being resized, and so on.
>
> Pass true for the immediate parameter to cause debounce to trigger the
>   function on the leading instead of the trailing edge of the wait
>   interval. Useful in circumstances like preventing accidental
>   double-clicks on a "submit" button from firing a second time.

```
var lazyLayout = _.debounce(calculateLayout, 300);
$(window).resize(lazyLayout);
```