# how to do a simple global cooldown using discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I have a new discord bot and newish to programming, like I kinda understand it but can't do it on my own. but on to the question.  The bot is all in the .js (I do have the config.json) but I have yet to get event handler to work.  but my code is.

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
 
    if (message.content.includes ("John")) {
      message.channel.send ("Oh yeah, that guy...");
    }
}
```

How can I get a global cooldown?  I want the cooldown so if a convo about John occurs, the bot isn't gonna respond to every message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wait before a javascript function can be called again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24481532/wait-before-a-javascript-function-can-be-called-again)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var cooldown = false;
client.on("message", (message) => {
      if (message.author.bot) return;

      if (message.content.includes("John")) {
        if (cooldown == true) {

          //Bot is on a cooldown
          return;

        } else {
          message.channel.send("Oh yeah, that guy...");

          cooldown = true;
          setTimeout(() => {
            cooldown = false
          }, 60000); //Timeout for a minute
        }
      }
    }
```

Kinda new to discord programming myself but this is similar to what I used.

Comment: This was very helpful, I just had to give the cooldown var a new name like johnCD. Thanks for taking the time to help a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest thing to do is create a variable outside the listener, with a timestamp, and compare current timestamp to the one set outside the scope, like so

```
var lastReply = 0;
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (Date.now() - lastReply < 10000) return; // don't respond within 10 seconds
    lastReply = Date.now();
    if (message.author.bot) return;
 
    if (message.content.includes ("John")) {
      message.channel.send ("Oh yeah, that guy...");
    }
}
```

I've set it to 10 seconds, but you can of course get this from a config, or change it yourself. For clarity (easy reading) you can also set a value like this (for lets say, 5 minutes): `lastReply < 5 * 60 * 1000`

Comment: Yes, I think that sounds like it'll do what I want.  but will lastReply only let the cooldown   if "John" command or cool down all bot commands?

Comment: I think I added a word in my question that I shouldn't have... (the global part)  but I think I can manage it from here.  Thank you